# What does it physically mean to take the Laplace transform of a non-periodic position function?

Tags: fourier-transform

What I'm trying to get through my head here is how taking the Laplace transform of a system with a position function like

$$X(t)=t$$

is possible.

To my current (admittedly incomplete) understanding, what a Laplace transform is doing to a system physically is defining it in terms of its frequency based on its time function.  However, the frequency of a system is defined as the number of cycles it goes through in a given amount of time, and if its position function looks like the above one (or any non-periodic function of $t$) I don't see how it's possible to define it in terms of frequency, and yet the transform of such a system is given as:

$$L[X(t)]=\frac{1}{s^2}$$

If anyone could explain this it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well if it means anything more, it's a *complex* frequency domain.

Comment: I suppose that could explain what I'm asking - if the complex frequency of the system has no real part it could still be a purely imaginary complex number `Im[s]`.

Comment: There's no requirement that a function be periodic to have a Laplace transform , simply that it be integrable from zero to infinity.

Comment: But what is a Laplace transform doing to a system physically, then, to spit out true answers?  Mathematical manipulations of physical dimensions are almost always based on sound, intuitive principles unless you're dealing with quantum physics which this isn't strictly speaking.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a Laplace transform is no different than doing a transform from rectangular to polar coordinates. It's simply a different way of visualizing the problem.

If you wish to think of it physically to help with your intuition, it helps to look at the actual transform:

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt,$$

where $s=\sigma+j\omega$.  Picking any "complex frequency" $s$, we can compute a value for the Laplace transform.  We don't usually compute values this way, because it's not usually a useful way to use the Laplace transform, but it can help with the intuition for what $s$ is.

Now if we substitute in a value for $s$ we get

$$F(\sigma+j\omega)=\int_0^\infty e^{-(\sigma+j\omega)t}f(t)dt.$$

Distributing the $t$ in the exponential we can get
$$F(\sigma+j\omega)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\sigma t-j\omega t}f(t)dt.$$

We can then break the exponential apart using the rules for subtracting exponents to get

$$F(\sigma+j\omega)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\sigma t}e^{-j\omega t}f(t)dt.$$

For one last step before the "complex frequency" bit makes sense, we apply Euler's formula to convert $e^{-j\omega t}$ to $\cos(-\omega t) + j\sin(-\omega t)$.  With this we get to the final equation:
$$F(\sigma+j\omega)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\sigma t}[\cos(-\omega t) + j\sin(-\omega t)]f(t)dt$$

Now we can start to see the "complex frequency" bit come out.  The imaginary part of the "complex frequency" turns into an oscillation in our weighting term.  The higher this part is, the higher the frequency of the oscillation.  Consider if $f(t)$ was a sine or cosine function.  We know that every sine and cosine is orthogonal to all other sines and cosines.  This means that if $f(t)$ was $\sin(2t)$, the only non-zero parts of the Laplace transform would be $\omega=2$ and $\omega=-2$.  This gives this term a frequency-like characteristic.  If your signal had a detectable frequency in it, you'd pick it up.

The real portion of the complex frequency is attached to an exponential decay (unless it's negative, but most Laplace transforms are ill defined in that domain).  The higher $\sigma$ gets, the more focused we are on the short term transients.  As $\sigma$ approaches $0$, $s$ captures more of the steady state oscillations in the system.  As $\sigma$ approaches infinity, $s$ captures more of the transients.

In the end, this is all just to make some intuitive sense of the Laplace transform.  In reality, the Laplace transform is used because it does a good job of making sense of linear systems of differential equations (something that is not immediately evident from exploring the "meaning" of a complex frequency).  The transform "spreads out" the information across the complex plane in such a way that many relationships which required solving differential equations can be solved using basic algebra.  It's that ability to turn differential equations into algebra that really matters.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you don't want to take a Laplace transform just to prove it can be done.  For mathematical systems that are the solution to 1st and 2nd order differential equations (i.e., from the process control world), in which several physical pieces of equipment are interacting with each other (e.g., the final outlet composition of a series of stirred tanks whereby the compositions are changing in time), multiplication of the equations leads to a big mess.  Laplace transforms integrate time out of the problem, and the problem becomes strictly an algebra problem in the Laplace domain. Once the algebra is solved, appropriate manipulations, such as partial fraction expansions, get the problem into a form that can be inverse transformed to get back to a solution in the time domain.

I'm sure that you have already seen the math behind problems such as this, but the point that I am trying to make is this - I doubt that there is a physical interpretation of what Laplace transforms are doing, precisely because time does not exist in the Laplace domain.

Comment: Thank you, I realize that this is a real possibility - the reason I believed that there might be a physical interpretation is because `s` is typically defined as the "complex frequency" of a system and frequency has a physical meaning, but I suppose it could also just be a term we use.